# How to turn 2-D list into a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm very new to Python and struggling a bit with lists and dicts.

Currently I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
exercises = [["Crawls", "Squats", "Climbers"], [10, 20, 30], ["metres", "reps", "seconds"]]
```

and I am hoping I can turn it into this, which would be much more useful:

```
exercises = [{"exercise_name": "Crawls",
              "set": 10,
              "set_type": "metres"},
             {"exercise_name": "Squats",
              "set": 20,
              "set_type": "reps"},
             {"exercise_name": "Climbers",
              "set": 30,
              "set_type": "seconds"}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "unzip" it then turn it into a dict with a list comprehension:

```py
[{
    "exercise_name": a,
    "set": b,
    "set_type": c
} for (a, b, c) in zip(*exercises)]
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! If your question got answered, make sure to [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so people know that it's been answered.